# How to register TestExecutionListener in Junit 5 and detect if all tests are executed

Tags: java, junit, java-8, junit5

Hi I am trying to implement integration test using JUNIT 5 as a framework and we just want to start all the process once before all the test are executed and stop all when all tests are executed.

I found there is no easy way to do this as we have many test class and the BeforeAll and AfterAll method works per test class

What i found , i might be able to do that if i can register my own custom listeners but somehow it didnt work

```
import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
        import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener;
        import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestPlan;

@AutoService(TestExecutionListener.class)
public class StateExecutionListener implements TestExecutionListener {

    public void testPlanExecutionStarted(TestPlan testPlan) {
        System.out.println("##########testPlanExecutionStarted "+testPlan.getRoots());
    }

    public void testPlanExecutionFinished(TestPlan testPlan) {
        System.out.println("##########testPlanExecutionStarted "+testPlan.getRoots());
    }

}
```

Any idea how can we register our own listeners / any other way to detect if all test cases are executed?
I use gradle JunitPlatform to run my tests

Answer (score 11):

To add on to Sam's answer:

1. Assuming you have a class `MyExecutionListener` which implements `TestExecutionListener`, create a file `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener`
2. Inside the file put the reference of `MyExecutionListener` (i.e, `com.blah.x.y.z.MyExecutionListener`)

An example of this can be found on the official JUnit 5 repository: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/bd339a570a04d86b92a89e31bbecc59475692e2c/platform-tests/src/test/resources/testservices/META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener

Answer (score 7):

To have your `TestExecutionListener` automatically registered, you have to do that via Java's `ServiceLoader` mechanism as described in the JUnit 5 User Guide:

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom