# @ExtendWith getting executed in every test class, rather than only once

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I am trying to create extensions A_Extension and B_Extension, which will get executed only once at start and at the end of all test classes.
Where as, I want to call C_Extension always in each test class.

Here are my extensions and test classes.

```
public class A_Extension implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {
    private static boolean isInitialized = false;
    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            //Do something and return ABC
            isInitialized = true;
            context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("ABC", ABC);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws Throwable {
        ABC = null;
    }
}

public class B_Extension implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource {
    private static boolean isInitialized = false;
    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            //Do something and return PQR
            isInitialized = true;
            context.getRoot().getStore(GLOBAL).put("PQR", PQR);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws Throwable {
        PQR = null;
    }
}

public class C_Extension implements AfterEachCallback, AfterAllCallback, BeforeAllCallback {
    //some extension code
}

@ExtendWith({A_Extension.class,B_Extension.class})
class TestClass1 {
    
    @RegisterExtension
    static C_Extension cExtension = new C_Extension();
            
    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAllClass() {  }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAllClass() {   }
    
    @Test
    void case1() {  }
    
    @Test
    void case2() {  }
}

@ExtendWith({A_Extension.class,B_Extension.class})
class TestClass2 {  
    @RegisterExtension
    static C_Extension cExtension = new C_Extension();
            
    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAllClass() {  }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAllClass() {}
    
    @Test
    void case1() {}
    
    @Test
    void case2() {}
}
```

But A_Extension.class and B_Extension.class are getting called always in each test case.
What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: "BeforeAll" and "AfterAll" in JUnit 5 mean presicely the "before/after all tests in a fixture(the class)". There is no API that would be triggered before or after a suite of several classes.

Comment: This might be a useful link for you: https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers

Comment: Also, there is an API that allows you to react to start and stop of the whole test plan, the `TestExecutionListener`. This question discusses how you can register it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754194/how-to-register-testexecutionlistener-in-junit-5-and-detect-if-all-tests-are-exe